# values from two consecutive line in bash

Tags: awk

I have file formatting like this:

```
0    10
1    20
2    40
5    50
...
a(i)    b(i)
a(i+1)  b(i+1)
a(i+2)  b(i+2)
...
```

I'd like to take averages of sub-periods from each line (line 1 and line 2), (line2 and line 3),... like this:

```
(0+1)/2            (20+10)/(1+0)
(1+2)/2            (40+20)/(2+1)
(2+5)/2            (50+40)/(5+2)
...
[a(i)+a(i+1)]/2    [b(i)+b(i+1)]/[a(i)+a(i+1)]
[a(i+1)+a(i+2)]/2  [b(i+1)+b(i+2)]/[a(i+1)+a(i+2)]
```

Can awk command do that?

Comment: Did you try something on your own?

Comment: It's a bit hard for me. I haven't got any idea.

Comment: Do you want the results of those expressions in the output, or the expressions themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following `awk` script. It uses two variable pa, pb (previous value of a, previous value b) to perform calculation between lines

```
awk '
NR>1 { print ($1+pa)/2, ($2+pb)/($1+pa) }
{ pa=$1 ; pb=$2  }
' < input-file
```